# Does pointer arithmetic still work outside the array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, language-lawyer

I am always reading that pointer arithmetic is defined as long as you don't leave the bounds of the array. I am not sure I completely understand what this means and I was a little worried. Hence this question.

Suppose I start with a pointer to the beginning of an array:

```
int *p = (int*) malloc(4 * sizeof(int));
```

Now I create two new pointers that lie outside the bounds of the array:

```
int *q = p + 10;
int *r = p - 2;
```

Now the pointers `q-10`, `q-9`, ..., `r+2`, `r+3`, and so on all lie inside the bounds of the array. Are they valid? For example, is `r[3]` **guaranteed** to give the same result as `p[1]`?

I have done some testing and it works. But I want to know if this is covered by the usual C specifications. Specifically, I am using Visual Studio 2010, Windows, and I am programming in native C (not C++). Am I covered?

Comment: @Chris post that as an answer

Comment: As long as the dereferencing of the address points to the block of memory, all of which are inside bound, then the behavior should be defined.

Comment: @chris If you post that as an answer, please, add some more details. I am asking  the question because I already read that and it wasn't completely clear to me.

Comment: @becko, I'm not exactly sure *why* it's UB, I just remembered it was, so I found where it's stated.

Comment: @chris: Historically, the *why* is segmented memory; while pointers might involve a segment and offset component, a compiler could do the arithmetic just on the offset component to avoid runtime cost. This makes arithmetic between pointers not in the same segment invalid.

Comment: @R.., That makes sense. I think it'd work well as part of your answer.

Comment: @R.. You should insert that last comment in your answer.

Comment: Good point. I expanded on it a bit and added it to my answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you're doing works on the implementation you're using, as well as most popular implementations, but it's not conforming C. As chris cited,

> §6.5.6/8: If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the behavior is undefined

The fact that it's undefined will probably become increasingly important in the future, with more advanced static analysis allowing compilers to turn this kind of code into fatal errors without incurring runtime cost.

By the way, the historical reason for subtracting pointers not within the same array being undefined is segmented memory (think 16-bit x86; those familiar with it will want to think of the "large" memory model). While pointers might involve a segment and offset component, a compiler could do the arithmetic just on the offset component to avoid runtime cost. This makes arithmetic between pointers not in the same segment invalid since the "high part" of the difference is lost.

Comment: In addition to issues regarding x86-style segmentation, it may also be helpful for compilers--especially in some "troubleshooting" scenarios, to have each "pointer" actually hold three addresses--the start and end of the allocated region of which the pointed-to- object is a part, as well as a pointer to the object itself, and use such information to trap code which would perform invalid pointer computations.  Trapping erroneous pointer computations when they occur can often greatly facilitate the tracking down of pointer-related bugs, and the Standard doesn't want to forbid that.

Comment: @supercat: Absolutely. Advanced pointer representations aimed at helping to diagnose/catch usage errors, or even make the system provably memory-safe (this is possible!), are great reasons for maintaining the C language's restrictions on pointer arithmetic.

Comment: IMHO, the proper thing for the Standard to do in many such cases would be to define __STDC_* macros which would indicate what guarantees the compiler will or won't provide as presently configured.  Since many compilers have options that can guarantee behaviors in cases not required by the Standard, being able to precede existing code that relies upon such semantics with `#if (__STDC_GUARANTEES && !__STDC_DIRECT_LINEAR_POINTERS) #error This code requires direct linear pointer semantics. #endif` would ensure that moving to a new C17 compiler would not cause the code to behave erroneously.

Comment: It may be that the only way to make the code *usable* with a new compiler would be to rewrite it so as not to require such semantics, but the need for rewrite would become apparent when it arose.  If within the useful lifetime of the code it never becomes necessary to use it with a compiler that can't support such semantics, rewriting the code for compatibility with such compilers impose huge costs but negative benefit (since any mistakes in the rewrite could add bugs to code whose behavior would otherwise have been correct when evaluated using the specified semantics).

Comment: @supercat: There's already a way to get compile-time errors when the application requires munging pointers as integers and the implementation doesn't support it: the cast to `uintptr_t` is an error because the (optional) type `uintptr_t` is not defined. Of course there's a theoretical case where the type/conversion is defined but not a flat linear mapping, so if that would break your application too you need to deal with it in some other way...

Comment: Although I don't think 8086 compilers happened to declare a type named `uintptr_t`, there's no reason they couldn't have done so.  On most x86 compilers not using mixed-memory-mode code, if `ptr` is an `int*`, (ptr-1)+1 would likely yield `ptr` when given any pointer to a valid object, but if `ptr` points to the start of a segment, `ptr-1` would compare greater than `ptr`.  I wouldn't call 8086 a "theoretical" architecture.  It wasn't an especially good fit for C, since one of the keys to writing efficient 8086 code is to use 16-bit segment-only pointers and C has no such concept, but...

Comment: ...I'd say the concept behind the segment:offset pointers is having a reappearance in some JVM implementations (which will access byte 123 of an object whose reference is stored as a 32-bit value 45678 by computing 45678*8+123).  In any case, if one has existing code that works on implementations where, given `char *x,*y`, the expression `x+(y-x);` will always yield `y`, allowing such code to specify that it should only compile on platforms which guarantee such semantics would seem better than blindly hoping nobody tries to migrate the code without rewriting it.

Answer (score 6):

According to the C11 standard, §6.5.6/8 (I put in the first part for context):

> When an expression that has integer type is added to or subtracted from a pointer
>   ...
>   If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

Therefore, a result that is outside of the array and not one past the end is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Which is funny because `p + 2 - 2` is defined, but `p - 2 + 2` is undefined. So much for associativity...

Comment: @Mysticial: Indeed. By the way, this brings up an easy-to-make error. Code like `ptr + index - base_index` is wrong and invokes UB if `index` goes outside the bounds of the pointed-to array. The alternate forms `ptr + (index - base_index)` or `&ptr[index-base_index]` are usually what you need. I've made this mistake a number of times myself.

Comment: @Mysticial Exactly! That's why I thought it was weird.

Comment: @R.. But this mistake has resulted in an actual error? Or just, say, a warning?

Comment: @becko I routinely break this rule when I do manual loop-unrolling. But the pointers that I pass in are typically a small portion of a much larger memory section.

Comment: Not that exact issue, but a similar one has led to a major error. I was mistakenly adding a moderately over-large offset to a base pointer to get an "end pointer", then looping as long as the pointer was less than the end pointer. The code worked fine on i386-linux running native on 32-bit processors (where pointers in the 3-4gb range never occur) and on x86_64 processors, but failed in i386 code running on a 64-bit kernel, since the stack got put very close to 0xffffffff and the addition overflowed. The result was a bad crash that was difficult to track down.

Comment: Here's a link to the fix for the bug I was talking about: http://git.musl-libc.org/cgi-bin/cgit.cgi?url=musl/commit/&id=914949d321448bd2189bdcbce794dbae2c8ed16e

Comment: +1, but I am marking @R.. answer, because it speaks of the general implementation I am using, which was my actual question.

Answer (score -1):

"Yes" the conditions you mentioned are covered in specifications.

```
    int *r = p - 2;
```

r is outside bounds of array p, the evaluation results in allocation of position to r, 2 int positions behind/before the address of p.

```
`r[3]` is simply the "4th" int position after the address of r
```