# What happens when you cast an int to an int*?

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, pointer-arithmetic

```
int val{ 100 };
int* ptr1 = (int*)val;
int* ptr2 = ptr1 + 5;
std::cout << ptr2 << '\n' << (int)ptr2 << std::endl;
```

In this code example the result of `(int*)val` is `00000064`, but I don't understand why. I also don't understand why `(int)ptr2` is `120`.

Comment: `int* ptr2 = ptr1 + 5;` invokes *undefined behavior*

Comment: What did you expect instead of `120` and why?

Comment: `64` in hexadecimal is `100`, which is exactly what you assign the pointer to.

Comment: you can't cast an int to an int-pointer. dereferencing such a pointer causes undefined behaviour. use: int* ptr1 = &val;

Comment: `std::cout << ptr2 << '\n' << (int)ptr2 << std::endl;` ... sure you are printing (int*)val anywhere there?

Comment: @UnholySheep Why is that? That looks like defined behavior to me. It'll probably not point to anything useful so dereferencing it won't work, but I don't see how that's undefined behavior.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman pointer arithmetic is only defined within the bounds of an array (including up to one past the end). So `ptr1 + 1` would be ok (since a single element is treated as a one element array), but `ptr1 + 2` is already UB

Comment: @TedKleinBergmann Also surprised that this is UB, I expected it to be "mathematically fine, but just pointing to garbage". Thanks! :) Found this interesting: [pointer arightmatics and UB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56360316/c-standard-regarding-pointer-arithmetic-outside-arrays)

Comment: @UnholySheep since `ptr1` doesn't point to any object, even `ptr1+1` is UB.

Comment: Are you asking why the difference between ptr1 and ptr2 is 20 istead of say 5?

Answer (score 3):

Analyzing line per line:

```
int* ptr1 = (int*)val;
```

Assign the **decimal value** `100` to the pointer `ptr1`;

```
int* ptr2 = ptr1 + 5;
```

This instuction invokes **undefined behaviour**, *the algebric operation over pointer is allowed only in array context.*

```
std::cout << ptr2 << '\n' << (int)ptr2 << std::endl;
```

**This instruction can print everything due to the previous undefined behaviour.**

The the result of `(int*)val` is `00000064` because is the representation of decimal value `100` in **hexadecimal notation**

Comment: Suggested improvement: Add the information that `ptr2` ends up being 120 because that is `5 * sizeof( int )` (i.e. that pointer arithmetic increments in `sizeof( T )` steps). Plus (and that helped me a lot understanding pointers back then), add that *dereferencing* a pointer is only valid (i.e., not UB) *if it actually points to an object of the given type*.

Answer (score 1):

Step by step:

```
int* ptr1 = (int*)val;
```

After executing this instruction ptr1 has decimal value 100 (00000064 in hexadecimal).

```
int* ptr2 = ptr1 + 5;
```

Now ptr2 has the same memory adress of ptr1, shifted by 5 units. It is shifted by 5 * (4 bytes) = 20 bytes. The memory address represented by ptr2 is (00000078)
This is the reason why (int)ptr2 is 120 (100 + 20).

Can this reasoning make sense?

Comment: This actually makes a lot of sense. So behind the scenes the compiler performs pointer arithmetic on ptr1 + 5, actually writing it as: ptr1 + 5 * sizeof(int)?

Comment: Yes, I definitely think so @OliverLambreghts